# Is it possible to use Brackets to edit CSS locally and live preview it in online server?

Tags: brackets, live-preview, macrabbit-espresso

This is something I used to do when working with (MacRabbit) Espresso app. Writing local CSS and seeing how changes work in the online website in real-time (Espresso calls it "Overrides"). It was especially useful when working with WordPress.

Is it possible to do it (or something similar) in Brackets?

Comment: I used brackets briefly before moving to vs-code, If I recall correctly there should be a button with a lightening bolt symbol to start the live preview which will run the html file in google chrome

Comment: Run the local html. I would like to override the online (remote server) html.